# Increasing nature of inverse function

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $a+b=k$ where $a \lt k/2$ and $\frac{d(g(x)}{dx} \gt 0$ if $b-a$ increases then the question is to find which of the following options are correct

$$A. \int_0^a g^{-1}(x) dx +\int_0^b g^{-1}(x) dx \text{   increases}$$

$$B. \int_0^a \frac{1}{g^{-1}(x)} dx +\int_0^b \frac{1}{g^{-1}(x)} dx \text{ decreases (given that $g^{-1}x \neq 0$ for any x)}$$

$$C. \int _0^a g(x) dx +\int_0^b g(x) dx \text{ increases}$$

Since $a \lt k/2$ it implies $b \gt k/2$ and $g(x)$ is a increasing function if $b$ increases or $a$ decreases. Therefore since $b$ increases and $g(x)$ increases therfore $\int_0^b g(x) dx$ increases. I couldnot conclude anything from this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a function g(x), which is (monotonically) increasing over an entire interval (a,b), then what must be true about its inverse g−1(x) over the same interval?

Comment: Is there some metadata, as "only one is true"?

Comment: @RafaBudria it is a multiple correct type question(More than one options may be correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b-a$ increases, $b$ increases. $a=k-b$ and $b\gt a$. Let

$$I_1=\int_0^{k-b}g(x)dx +\int_0^{b}g(x)dx$$

It's increasing,

$$\dfrac{dI_1}{db}=-g(k-b)+g(b)=g(b)-g(a)>0$$

because $g'\gt0\implies g$ is monotonically increasing.

Now,

$$I_2=\int_0^{k-b} \frac{1}{g^{-1}(x)} dx +\int_0^{b} \frac{1}{g^{-1}(x)} dx$$

Decreasing

$$\dfrac{dI_2}{db}= \frac{-1}{g^{-1}(k-b)}+ \frac{1}{g^{-1}(b)}=\frac{1}{g^{-1}(b)}-\frac{1}{g^{-1}(a)}\lt0$$

because

$\left(\dfrac{1}{g^{-1}}\right)'=-\left(\dfrac{1}{g^{-1}}\right)^2=-(g')^2\lt0$ so is, $(1/g^{-1})'$ is monotonically decreasing.

$$I_3=\int_0^{k-b}g^{-1}(x)dx +\int_0^{b}g^{-1}(x)dx$$

It's increasing

$$\dfrac{dI_3}{db}=-g^{-1}(k-b)+g^{-1}(b)=g^{-1}(b)-g^{-1}(a)\gt0$$

because

$(g^{-1})'=\dfrac{1}{g'}\gt0$, $g^{-1}$ is monotonocally increasing too.